# How to change state:activated after tapping on another image view?

Tags: android, xml

I have five icons inside five different `ImageViews`, i wanted to change the icons once the user tap on them, i got it by `android:state_activated="true"` and by adding two different icons for each source, it worked but now i want the images o go back to the previous image when user tap on a different icon.

here's my code:
**image-changeable.xml :**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homeiconbig" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homeicon" />
</selector>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
view.setActivated(true);
```

Comment: Did you tried with `view.setActivited(false)`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in  image-changeable.xml:-

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/homeicon" android:state_activated="false" />
```

and In Main Activity try this:-

```
 view.setActivated(false);
```

Comment: doesn't work, it makes the image static even after touch

Answer (score 0):

How about you change your code in MainActivity to

```
boolean isActivated = view.isActivated();
view.setActivated(!isActivated);
```

Comment: this in a sense work, but only when i click the same icon, i want the icon to go back the first image even when i click anywhere in the screen

Comment: So you meant, clicking on anywhere even not on any icons also get the activated icon back to the previous state (inactivated)?

Comment: no, clicking on any other icon will revert the icon go back to the previous state that inactivated, but with your solution it only go to the previous state after clicking on itself

Comment: Got it! I guess it should be just the logic how you update the view's state when user taps on those icons.

- Tap the activated icon -> reset it
- Tap the other inactivated icon -> reset all other icons to inactivated state, than update the current one to activated state.